# Is there limit of iPhone for push notification?

Tags: iphone

**how many notification send for iPhone in a single day? 
Is there any Daily limit ?**

Comment: Yes there is throttling in place, people don't know how it works specifically, Apple doesn't publish it which means they could even change it if necessary.

Comment: if i want to send push for iPhone and i have no of devices. How can i manage the limit for this .. if i don't have limit.

Comment: Well how many are you wanting to send? Think of what you would be OK with as a user of your app. I imagine getting an notification every minute is going to be a PITA. Getting one every hour is still verging on unacceptable and that's only 24 per day. If the user has an alarm set to go every hour then that's different... but then it should be a local notification not a remote so limits are irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

There is no published set limit for push notifications. However, Apple does say in a TechNote "There are no caps or batch size limits for using APNs."

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG34

They also say "If you're seeing throughput lower than 9,000 notifications per second, your server might benefit from improved error handling logic," implying that they expect usage to be pretty high.

I imagine, though, that if you cause Apple to incur a very large number they will be looking into your usage to ensure that it's not all spam and that you are making a good faith effort to prune devices that have turned notifications off using Apple's Feedback service.

At least one app, AppGratis, has been removed from the app store for abusing them.

http://allthingsd.com/20130408/confirmed-apple-kicks-appgratis-out-of-the-store-for-being-too-pushy/

Other limits to keep in mind: The maximum size allowed for a notification payload is 256 bytes, and only the most recent notification will be sent to the user if multiple are sent while their device is offline/unavailable.

**UPDATE:** Per Fogmeister, the per-notification size limit has been increased to 1 KB.

Comment: The bundle limit was recently upped to 1kb. I think... going to have to find out. I'm sure it was in a WWDC video, lol. Here you go... http://docs.urbanairship.com/dashboard/july-2014-release.html#apns-payload-size-increase